# Replace all object properties with a new name

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I want to replace all object properties `label` to the property name `text`.

Given:

```
[
  {
    "value": "45a8",
    "label": "45A8",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "45a8.ba08",
        "label": "BA08",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "45a8.ba08.45a8",
            "label": "45A8"
          }
        ],
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Needed:

```
[
  {
    "value": "45a8",
    "text": "45A8",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "45a8.ba08",
        "text": "BA08",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "45a8.ba08.45a8",
            "text": "45A8"
          }
        ],
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first stringify the the data with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) then replace the string. Finally parse the string with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var data = [
  {
    "value": "45a8",
    "label": "45A8",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "45a8.ba08",
        "label": "BA08",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "45a8.ba08.45a8",
            "label": "45A8"
          }
        ],
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  }
];

data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replaceAll('"label"', '"text"'));
console.log(data);
```

**Update:** You can try using RegEx like the following way:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "value": "45a8",
    "label": "45A8",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "45a8.ba08",
        "label": "BA08",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "45a8.ba08.45a8",
            "label": "45A8"
          }
        ],
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  }
];
var find = '"label"';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(re, '"text"'));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I already tried that but this is not changing the property of the children elements.

Comment: @mrks, use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`, please check updated the answer:)

Comment: Thanks for the quick change but `replaceAll` does not exist on type `string` unfortunately.

Comment: @mrks, you can try the second solution  using *regex* in the updated answer:)

Answer (score 2):

You can also browse through the keys and find the label key. Get it's value assign it to the new key i.e. text and delete the old key i.e. label.

```
let data = [
      {
        "value": "45a8",
        "label": "45A8",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "45a8.ba08",
            "label": "BA08",
            "children": [
              {
                "value": "45a8.ba08.45a8",
                "label": "45A8"
              }
            ],
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    
    for (const key in data.keys()){
      if(key === "label"){
        data.text = data[key]
        delete data.key
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with using `recursion`. It could be something like this:

```js
const nestArr=[ { "value": "45a8", "label": "45A8", "children": [ { "value": "45a8.ba08", "label": "BA08", "children": [ { "value": "45a8.ba08.45a8", "label": "45A8" } ], "checked": false } ] }];

changeLabelToText=arr=>{
    return arr.map(({label,...rest})=>{
      if(rest.children) rest.children = changeLabelToText(rest.children);
      return {text:label, ...rest}
    })
};

console.log(changeLabelToText(nestArr));
```